# Alternative (cooler) CPU than a Intel Celeron M 420 1.6GHz?

Tags: cpu, cooling, toshiba-laptop, overheating

I bought a broken Toshiba Satellite A105-S2101 laptop off eBay. It would freeze on the BIOS loading screen; I found out it was just a bad DVD drive. I replaced it and all is well, except it overheats and shuts off after approximately 15 minutes.

Specifications:

- it has an Intel Celeron M 420; it’s a Socket M,
- the fan works, of course,
- the heat sink is clean,
- the thermal paste was pretty dry, so I ordered some; it’ll be here in a few days,

If it still acts up after new paste, would one of the other Socket M CPUs better as far as staying cooler? It doesn't necessarily have to be faster.

According to CPU-World these are the available Socket M CPUs,

- Intel Core Solo
- Intel Core Duo
- Intel Celeron M 400 series
- Intel Celeron M 500 series
- Intel Pentium Dual-Core Mobile
- Intel Core 2 Duo Mobile

I read on a Yahoo Answers post that Celeron M's are known for getting hot, and even a Core Duo would run cooler.

But the info on the Xpress 200M chipset says it supports "Intel® Pentium® M, Intel® Celeron®, Celeron® M and Intel® Pentium® 4 processors"

THEN a guy at this link ([Notebook Review Post](http://forum.notebookreview.com/toshiba/109094-a135-xpress-200-667mhz-duo-core-compatible.html)) says he bought a Core Duo CPU and put it into a similar laptop with the same chipset and it worked, so I don’t know what to think.

Anyone have more knowledge on this?

I would like to get a Core Duo T2300E if it would work, and if it would run cooler, they have them less than $10 all day long on eBay. I just going to resell the laptop after I get the overheating problem fixed.

Comment: Make sure you have a BIOS version which supports the new CPU.

Comment: Your choices on a laptop are limited to the point the aftermarket on cpu coolers does not exist.  Your limited to laptop coolers with fans that blow air into the case ( depending on air vent placement ) or cooling pads.

Comment: I don't think this will be solved by a new CPU. Replace the thermal paste, lower the fan 'kick-in' speed (so it spins up at a lower temp), lower the CPU tolerance of heat ~5°C (so it slows down when overheating - less speed, less generated heat), and get a laptop cooling pad like Ramhound suggested.